# Query in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to create new task in the list. The url is "lists/1/newTask".

Tasks.php (model)

```
    class Tasks extends Model {

        protected $fillable=[
            'description'
        ];

        public function lists()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Lists');
        }
    }
```

Lists.php (model)

```
class Lists extends Model {

    protected $fillable=[
        'name'
    ];


    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tasks');
    }
}
```

Tasks table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->integer('list_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('list_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('lists')
              ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
}
```

So now I tried to store all data from form and create the task. I don't know how to use relationship and how to store NewTask with list_id = $id (from url)

I tried manually to store id in list_id like this, but it's not working

```
  public function store(CreateTasksRequest $request, $id)
    {

        $listID = Lists::findorfail($id);

        DB::table('tasks')->insert([
            ['description' => $request, 'list_id' => $listID]
        ]);


    }
```

I am new in this, so I must have surely done something wrong. 
Also it would be great if data storage could work automatically and not manually.

My route

```
Route::get('lists/{id}/newTask', 'TasksController@create');
Route::post('lists/{id}', 'TasksController@store');
```

Comment: I'd include "list_id" in the $fillable array of Tasks, and store it this way: ['description' => $request, 'list_id' => $id]

Comment: just tryed that. New task was created, but description is "POST /lists/1 HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: lv-LV,lv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2 Cache-Control"

Comment: Of course, because you are passing the full post as description. You have to extract the parameter "description" from the $request : $description = $request->input('description');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this more elegant approach: (from http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

```
$task = new Task(array('description' => $request->input('description')));

$list = Lists::find($id);

$task = $list->tasks()->save($task);
```

Comment: @NarendraSisodia Euh... what did you change? Curiosity, don't know how to see the historic...